# Issue with SSL, nginx, gunicorn, and Django in production

Tags: python, django, ssl, nginx, gunicorn

I'm having an issue getting nginx to pass over control of routing to my django server.  By default it checks '/' path and if the user isn't logged in redirects to '/login' and then upon login passes it back to '/'.  The login page works fine until you submit then it throws an 'Internal server error'.  The server is ubuntu 16.4.  Also the python is 3.5 and inside a virtualenv.  Let me know if I need to provide the gunicorn service config.

My nginx is as follows:

```
   server {
           server_name example.com;
           rewrite ^(.*) https://www.example.com permanent;
   }

   server {
           listen 80;
           server_name www.example.com;
           rewrite ^(.*) https://www.example.com permanent;
   }

   server {
           listen 443 ssl;
           server_name www.example.com;

           ssl on;
           ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/12345678.crt;
           ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl.key;

           location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
           location /static/ {root /home/ubuntu/app; }

           location / {
                       include proxy_params;
                       proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/app/app.sock;
           }
    }
```